# How to run Vim command from the shell?

Tags: linux, vim, shell, make

This might be a dumb question, but bear with me.

I'm automating some of the usual stuff I do when setting up a new work environment, and would like to automate the Vim command `:BundleInstall` (for installing all my Vim plugins).

Is it possible to run this from the shell?

Alternatively, is it possible to have the script run Vim, execute `:BundleInstall`, wait until it finishes and quit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the `vim(1)` man page:

> +{command}
>
> -c {command}
>
> {command} will be executed after the first file has been read. {command} is interpreted as an Ex command. If the {command} contains spaces it must be enclosed in double quotes (this depends on the shell that is used). Example: Vim "+set si" main.c
>
> Note: You can use up to 10 "+" or "-c" commands.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I'd feel dumb... :-/ Serves me right for not reading the manpage thoroughly. I ended up using `vim +BundleInstall +qall!`.

Answer (score 5):

You can execute your command like this:

```
vim -E -c BundleInstall -c q
```

which will avoid opening a Vim window in your terminal.

**Note:** My first answer included the `-s` option which I had needed for another application but was incorrect here because it prevented much of Vim's intialization including sourcing the plugin that defined the `BundleInstall` command.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it won't work for me.

Comment: Now I see why. I forgot that `-s` does more than inhibit certain messages--it also inhibits intializations--so the definition of BundleInstall wasn't being sourced. One way to fix that would be to add an option like this before the first `-c`: `--cmd 'runtime plugin/bundle.vim'`. Edit that file name to suit. See `:help -s-ex`.

Answer (score 3):

While the vim specific recipe above is the right way to do it, you can always use a more general approach like [autoexpect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/autoexpect).

Answer (score 0):

For situations where you need for vim to have fully loaded up as if you started it manually, this works:

```
vim -c "autocmd! CursorHold * <commands to run>"
```

For example, I wanted to redirect the output of `:map` to a file from the shell, but I wanted to capture the mapping that [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) creates only after it's displayed its tabline (line at top showing all buffernames open.)  Because it seems to do this asynchronously, simply running a `-c` redirect to a file wasn't giving it time to make the mappings.  There could be a better way, but this works for me, especially since I already have `updatetime` set to `100` (0.1 seconds), which affects how long until the `CursorHold` event fires.  By default, vim sets it to 4 seconds.

```
vim -c "autocmd! CursorHold * set nomore | redir! > mapNew | map | redir END | q"
```