# sending argument to vim using grep

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, vim, grep

I saw [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/451863/how-to-run-vim-command-from-the-shell) but I couldn't implement what I'm looking for.

Here is what I want:

- I have a file with a few lines ending with `4.1.01.97` (same number for all lines - but number can change from time to time)
- I want to open vim and change the number into another

I tried `vim [file_name] +:%s/97/98/g +:wq` which works fine but it wouldn't help if the file will change.

I next tried getting desired number with `grep`: `cat [file_name] | tail -1 | grep -E '.[0-9][0-9]$'`

I want to use the result of this in my vim command... Something like using `vim [file_name] +:%s/97/98/g +:wq` with the grep command inside ``, instead the `97`.

How can I do that?

*If this it possible without vim, that would also be helpful :)*

*Also, can my regular expression for the grep be improved?*

---

**This is how the file looks like:**

```
A_,4.1.01.97
B_,4.1.01.97
C_,4.1.01.97
D_,4.1.01.97
E_,4.1.01.97
F_,4.1.01.97
G_,4.1.01.97
H_,4.1.01.97
```

---

**This is how I want the file to look like:**

```
A_,4.1.01.98
B_,4.1.01.98
C_,4.1.01.98
D_,4.1.01.98
E_,4.1.01.98
F_,4.1.01.98
G_,4.1.01.98
H_,4.1.01.98
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sed` :

```
sed 's/97/98/g' /path/to/file.txt
```

Use `sed -i` to modiffy the file instead of printing to stdout:

```
sed -i 's/97/98/g' /path/to/file.txt
```

Edit:

Since you also wanted to know if your regex can be improved, here a suggestion to get the last number of the end of your lines:

```
tail -1  /path/to/file.txt | grep -o '[0-9]\{1,\}$'
```

If you want to obtain the highest integer found at the end of all lines in the file, you could:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{1,\}$' /path/to/file.txt | sort -n | tail -1
```

You could replace it in the file as such:

```
sed -i 's/[0-9]\{1,\}$/<your replacement here>/g' /path/to/file.txt
```

Later Edit:

You may use this one liner:

```
pattern=`tail -1 /path/to/file.txt | grep -o '[0-9]\{1,\}$'` && sed -i "s/[0-9]\{1,\}$/${pattern}/" /path/to/file.txt
```

Comment: This is helpful but it requires me to know what is written in the file. I want to not have to write "97" but a generic line...

Comment: Gotcha!  You can use the last command I added in my initial answer